# How to support device rotation from iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.3

Hello my app always supported device rotations, but now it don't and i can't find out why.
Maybe in app settings i should mark something new.

In controller's i have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
}
```

And in Project summary i marked that i am supporting all orientations. 
Maybe something changed as i didn't worked with iOS few months ?

Can i debug orientation changes why my app is in portrait mode?

Thanks.

Comment: this should be in your base controller at the first place to support it throughout the app.

Comment: It is and worked. with iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2, but now have Xcode 4.3.3 and app don't rotate

Comment: Check the supported orientations entry in your info.plist

Comment: Find the problem. I have tab bar with 4 items. I added 1 item to tab bar and didn't added shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. For this reasons all app didn't rotated. Strange first time found this behavior. Sorry for your time

Comment: Thank you, this saved the day for me.  I was building my app using storyboards, and I was working one tab at a time.  I couldn't figure out why the rotation wasn't working.  Because of your comment, I realized I needed to go ahead and add the shouldAutoRotate and SupportedInterfaces method to each controller.  Thanks again!!